# How to add 100 spaces at end of each line of a file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file which is supposed to contain 200 characters in each line. I received a source file with only 100 characters in each line. I need to add 100 extra white spaces to each line now. If it were few blank spaces, we could have used sed like:

```
 sed 's/$/     /' filename > newfilename
```

Since it's 100 spaces, can anyone tell me is it possible to add in Unix?

Comment: Do you want a fixed field length of 200 characters with some number of spaces added to make each line 200 characters long or you just want to add 100 spaces to an existing line?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have fixed n chars per line (don't trust the input file has exact m chars per line) follow this.  For the input file with varying number of chars per line:

```
$ cat file
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

extend to 10 chars per line.

```
$ awk '{printf "%-10s\n", $0}' file | cat -e

1         $
12        $
123       $
1234      $
12345     $
```

Obviously change 10 to 200 in your script.  Here `$` shows end of line, it's not there as a character.  You don't need `cat -e`, here just to show the line is extended.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated after Glenn's suggestion**

Somewhat how Glenn suggests in the comments, the substitution is unnecessary, you can just add the spaces - although, taking that logic further, you don't even need the addition, you can just `say` them after the original line.

```
perl -nlE 'say $_," "x100' file
```

**Original Answer**

With Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/$/" " x 100/e' file
```

That says... *"Substitute (`s`) the end of each line (`$`) with the calculated expression (`e`) of 100 repetitions of a space"*.

If you wanted to pad all lines to, say, 200 characters even if the input file was ragged (all lines of differing length), you could use something like this:

```
perl -pe '$pad=200-length;s/$/" " x $pad/e'
```

which would make up lines of 83, 102 and 197 characters to 200 each.

Comment: Don't really need search and replace. Just append the spaces to the line: `$_ .= " "x100`

Comment: Nicely done; since you're using `-l`, `say` is overkill, though: `perl -nle 'print $_," "x100' file`, or, with implicit printing, as implied by Glenn's comment: `perl -ple '$_ .= " "x100' file`

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s%100s\n", $0, ""}' file.dat
```

`$0` refers to the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are looking for a `bash` solution,

```
while IFS=  read -r line
    do
    printf "%s%100s\n" "$line" 
done < file > newfile
```

---

**Test**

Say I have a file with 3 lines it it as

```
$ wc -c file
      16 file
$ wc -c newfile
     316 newfile
```

---

**Original Answer**

```
spaces=$(echo {1..101} | tr -d 0-9)
while read line
    do
    echo -e "${line}${spaces}\n" >> newfile
done < file
```

Comment: For added efficiency, you could calculate `spaces` outside the loop.

Comment: Consider `printf` rather than `echo -e` (which -- unlike most bashisms which extend behavior undefined by the standard rather than breaking it outright -- violates POSIX compliance, and doesn't work when the `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are enabled, or in POSIX mode when bash was compiled with `--enable-xpg-echo-default`). See also the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [relevant standards document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: Also, frankly, `printf '%s%100s\n' "$line"` would be a lot shorter.

Comment: (Also, clear IFS for your loop and pass the `-r` flag to `read` -- otherwise, you're deleting preexisting trailing whitespace and removing backslashes! Thus: `while IFS= read -r line`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I am using `printf`, I can completely avoid the `echo | tr` pipes.

Comment: Clever to use brace expansion. However, you only get 99 spaces. Need `{1..101}` to get 100

Comment: Yup. (It also prevents sequences like `\\t` in the input document -- with the doubling needed due to the missing `-r` on `read` -- from being interpreted by `echo -e` and emitted as a literal tab; incidentally, if you *want* escape sequences in an argument other than the format string to be literally interpreted with printf, you can do that explicitly using `%b` -- but there's no call for it here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Have updated my answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: One more note -- if you put `> newfile` after the `done`, you'll be opening the output file only once, vs re-opening it every single time you want to run a `printf` that writes to it and closing it after that single `printf` completes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fixed that as well :)

Comment: @glennjackman ohh, I missed that. Was counting the `\n` as well. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use Bash, you can still use sed, but use some readline functionality to keep you from manually typing 100 spaces (see [manual for "Readline arguments"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Arguments)).

You start typing normally:

```
sed 's/$/
```

Now, you want to insert 100 spaces. You can do this by prepending hitting the space bar with a readline argument to indicate that you want it to happen 100 times, i.e., you manually enter what would look like this as a readline keybinding:

```
M-1 0 0 \040
```

Or, if your meta key is the alt key: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

This inserts 100 spaces, and you get

```
sed 's/$/                                                                                                    /' filename
```

after typing the rest of the command.

This is useful for working in an interactive shell, but not very pretty for scripts – use any of the other solutions for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` in `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s%*.s\n", $0, 100, " "}' filename > newfile
```

This `printf` will append 100 spaces at the end of each newline.

Answer (score 1):

Another way in `GNU awk` using [string-manipulation function `sprintf`.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

```
awk 'BEGIN{s=sprintf("%-100s", "");}{print $0 s}' input-file > file-with-spaces
```

A proof with an example:-

```
$ cat input-file
1234jjj hdhyvb 1234jjj
6789mmm mddyss skjhude
khora77 koemm  sado666
nn1004  nn1004 457fffy
$ wc -c input-file
      92 input-file
$ awk 'BEGIN{s=sprintf("%-100s", "");}{print $0 s}' input-file > file-with-spaces
$ wc -c file-with-spaces
      492 file-with-spaces
```

Comment: ++ for generating the string of spaces only _once_. `sprintf` is actually part of the POSIX Awk spec., so your command is POSIX-compliant. Slight optimization: `{ print $0 s }` instead of `{$0=$0 s}1` is probably faster, because the input line doesn't have to be split into fields again.